# Conditionally pipe output through sed

Tags: bash, sed, pipe, conditional-statements

Is there a way to conditionally pipe the output of a command through sed, in a bash script?  Depending upon a script option, I either want to pipe the output of a long pipe through sed, or omit the pipe through sed.  Currently I'm doing

```
if [ $pipeit ]; then
   sed_args='/omit this line/d'
else
   sed_args='/$^/d'  # pass-thru (what's a better sed pass thru?)
fi

some_cmd | sed "$sed_args"
```

Comment: Just realized my sed pass-through (a work around) doesn't do what I thought it might.  It matches the literal $^.

Comment: I've changed double quotes to single quotes where applicable. It was not wrong before, but kind of fragile and harder to read. Kind of fragile because the shell would indeed not try to expand `"$^"` since `^` is not a proper variable name, however, it would try to expand `"$abc"` (for example). That's why, if you don't want shell expansion happen, use single quotes.

Comment: @JoeRiel my answer had been updated, give it a look

Answer (score 3):

I would keep it as simple as:

```
if [ $pipeit ]; then
   some_cmd | sed '/omit this line/d'
else
   some_cmd
fi
```

Why should you call `sed` if you don't need it? Just for your information, a possible sed command that does not change the input would be `sed -n p`

Btw, if `some_cmd` is kind of a large beast and you want to avoid duplicating it, wrap it into a function.

Comment: That is not ideal here because some_cmd is actually a large construction (subshell), so it's best not to duplicate it. Yes, I'd like to omit the pipe if I could.  Is there a way with duplicating the preceding commands, as you show?  I had tried using `sed -n p`, but couldn't get that to work with one shell variable (`sed $sed_args`).  It can be done with two, but ...

Answer (score 1):

By default `sed` prints all lines:

```
if [ $pipeit ]; then
  sed_args='/omit this line/d'
else
  sed_args=""  # pass-thru
fi

some_cmd | sed "${sed_args}"
```

There is this other tested solution:

```
some_cmd | if [ $pipeit ]; then
  sed "/omit this line/d"
else 
  sed ""
fi
```

`cat` could be used instead of the `sed ""`

Finally, a string can be built and executed using `eval`.

```
some_cmd='printf "foo\n\nbar\n"'
if [ $pipeit ]; then
  conditional_pipe='| sed "/foo/d"'
else
  conditional_pipe=""
fi

eval "${some_cmd}" "${conditional_pipe}"
```

If `some_cmd` is complex it migth be tricky to build a string that would behave as expected with `eval`.

### ----

First solution for history

Using an impossible match with `sed` would make it print all lines to stdout:

```
$ printf "foo\n\nbar\n" | sed "/./{/^$/d}"
foo

bar
```

`/./` selects a line with at least one char.
`/^$/` selects an empty line.

Comment: Using `eval` is never ever a good idea. It's not just a saying, it's true!

Comment: All solutions are tested

Comment: @hek2mgl I think there is a miserstanding: Test `echo 1 | sed ""` instead

Comment: True, I was wrong with that. Since `""` is a program, even if empty, it works. Good catch

Comment: @hek2mgl I am surprised, usually my ideas are good ;)  I understand the `eval` command is risky, if there is specific situtaitons, you could share them with us or provide some links?

Comment: Thanks, Jay.  I went with your second suggestion, in which the conditional is in the pipe. It seemed the cleanest in that it doesn't require another shell variable. hek2mgl's suggestion to wrap the command in a function is reasonable, but the source for this is in noweb, which produces the bash script, and would require a fair amount of rework to update the documentation.